# Limit of $f_n(x)=\int _0^x\frac{1}{(e^t+e^{-t})^n}\,dt $

Tags: real-analysis, integration

We suppose the function defined as $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus{0} \quad f_n(x)=\int _0^x\dfrac{1}{(e^t+e^{-t})^n}\,dt $, and suppose it has a limit $\lambda_n$ at $+\infty$.

The questions are:

- Determine the relation between $\lambda_n$ and $\lambda_{n-2}$.
- Conclude that $\forall p\in \mathbb{N}\setminus{0} \quad \lambda_{2p+1}=\frac{(2p)!}{4^{2p}(p!)^2}\frac{\pi}{4}$.

**I already proved that $\dfrac{4}{(e^t+e^{-t})^n}=\dfrac{1}{(e^t+e^{-t})^{n-2}}-\dfrac{(e^t-e^{-t})^2}{(e^t+e^{-t})^n}$.**

Comment: Where is the $n$ dependency in $f_n$?

Comment: Note that $$(e^t+e^{-t})'=e^t-e^{-t}$$

Comment: If you could notice the following questions have a power n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a thought if it helps.

To show $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(e^{t}+e^{-t})^{2p+1}}dt=\frac{(2p)!\pi}{4^{2p}(p!)^{2}4}$, you can use the Beta function.

By writing as $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{(2p+1)t}}{(1+e^{2t})^{2p+1}}dt$, the sub $x=e^{t}$ can be made and thus obtaining

$\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2p}}{(1+x^{2})^{2p+1}}dx$

This can now be evaluated using the Beta function.

First note that $\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2p}}{(1+x^{2})^{2p+1}}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2p}}{(1+x^{2})^{2p+1}}dx$......[1]

The right side of which is the Beta. Evaluating results in the required solution.

Let $y=x^{2}$.  Making the subs results in:

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{y^{p-1/2}}{(1+y)^{2p+1}}dy$

$\displaystyle=\frac{\Gamma^{2}(p+1/2)}{\Gamma(2p+1)}$

But, $\displaystyle \Gamma(p+1/2)=\frac{(2p)!\sqrt{\pi}}{4^{p}p!}, \;\ \Gamma(2p+1)=(2p)!$

Using these identities and reducing a little results in

$\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{4}\cdot \frac{(2p)!}{4^{2p}(p!)^{2}}$ as required.